# Custom Quick Settings Tile Remains in Unavailable State when Bound to Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a custom quick settings tile for my application. I've followed the sample code/documentation from Google but I'm running into some issues. After searching for some time I couldn't find any solutions.

When I run my app, the tile is visible in the quick settings tray, but it remains in an unavailable state.

I need a two-way flow of communication with the tile, i.e., when the user selects the tile, the app responds and when the user does a certain action within the app, the tile UI is toggled.

The problem seems to come from attempting to bind my custom `TileService` class to my `MainActivity` -- whenever I bind it is when the tile goes into a consistently unavailable state. I can't seem to figure out why though because it's being bound successfully. If I don't bind it (i.e. just have the one way communication of the tile commanding the app), the tile is active and the app responds to selecting it.

Ultimately I do the binding to attain a reference to my custom `TileService` class to be able to call it's method `toggleTileUI()`. I'm not looking to use a singleton or static member variable as a solution to getting a reference to my service.

Here's what I have in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
        <service
            android:name=".ConnectionQuickSettingsService"
            android:label="@string/quick_setting_tile_connect"
            android:icon="@drawable/tile_icon"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Here's my `ConnectionQuickSettingsService.java`:

```java
@TargetApi(24)
public class ConnectionQuickSettingsService extends TileService {
    private static final String TAG = "ConnectionQuickSettingsService";
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
            ConnectionQuickSettingsService getService() {
                return ConnectionQuickSettingsService.this;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTileAdded() {
        L.d(TAG, "onTileAdded()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartListening() {
        L.d(TAG, "onStartListening()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        L.d(TAG, "Quick Settings tile selected");
        toggleInAppSwitch();
        toggleTileUI();
    }

    private void toggleInAppSwitch() {
        doStuff();
    }

    public void toggleTileUI() {
        Tile tile = this.getQsTile();
        doStuffWithTile();
    }

}
```

and lastly (the relevant parts of) my `MainActivity.java`:

```java
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ConnectionQuickSettingsService.class);
    bindService(i, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        ConnectionQuickSettingsService.LocalBinder binder = (ConnectionQuickSettingsService.LocalBinder) service;
        mQSService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
        L.d(TAG, "Bound to QS service successfully");
}

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
        L.d(TAG, "Disconnected from QS service");
    }
};

public void onOnOff(){
    L.d(TAG, "On/Off switch toggled");
    if (mBound) {
        mQSService.toggleTileUI();
    }
}
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you are overriding `onBind()`, which clobbers the `TileService` implementation of `onBind()`, preventing Android from working with your `ConnectionQuickSettingsService`. I would expect that there would be error messages in LogCat from a system process complaining about this.

The other part of your problem is that you assume that `getQsTile()` works at arbitrary points in time. [It doesn't](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.html#getQsTile()).

I recommend finding some other interaction pattern with your tile, such as using `META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE` and `requestListeningState()`, and getting rid of your `Binder` and `onBind()` method.

Comment: If I remove my `Binder` and `onBind()`, how will my `MainActivity` attain a reference to the `TileService` so that I can call `toggleTileUI()`?

Comment: @jcarnide: You get rid of all of that. `toggleTileUI()` will not work, because you cannot call `getQsTile()` whenever you feel like it. I recommend finding some other interaction pattern with your tile, such as using `META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE` and `requestListeningState()`.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding properly. I get that the tile is not always available via `getQsTile()` and that using `META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE` and `requestListeningState()` can make it active for use, but that doesn't solve the problem of how my `MainActivity` is going to communicate with the Tile. The tile UI needs to be in sync with the in-app UI (it's for switching a feature on and off), i.e., if the switch is ON in the app, the Tile needs to be "on" and have the appropriate label set etc...

Comment: @jcarnide: `MainActivity` calls `requestListeningState()`. Your `TileService` updates the tile sometime after `onStartListening()` and before `onStopListening()`. This requires `META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE`. Your `TileService` updates the tile using data pulled from some central, persistent data store.

Comment: My bad, I've just realized that the `requestListeningState()` is static. I'll give this a shot, thank you.

Comment: @jcarnide: Yeah, the communications path is unusual. Basically, what `requestListeningState()` is doing is pushing the system to pull an update from the `TileService`. So long as your `TileService` can deliver the right state (e.g., pull from `SharedPreferences`), you should be OK.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. So if I want to keep the Tile up-to-date from frequent user interactions in `MainActivity`, should I then be registering some sort of listener in `onStartListening()` or can I call `requestListeningState()` repeatedly to update the Tile?

Comment: @jcarnide: Well, I suspect that the vision is that the tile does not change too frequently. You could take the approach of using an event bus to try to optimize matters. The activity would post messages on the bus for the service to pick up indicating tile state changes. The service would be registered on the bus between `onStartListening()` and `onStopListening()`. If the activity determines that the service did not pick up the bus message, it uses `requestListeningState()` to request that Android start listening to the service again.

Comment: @jcarnide: Whether that sort of logic is "a great idea" or "premature optimization", I can't say. :-)

Comment: So for some reason `requestListeningState()` is not invoking `onStartListening()` when I call it from `MainActivity`'s `onOnOff()`. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @jcarnide: Did you add the `<meta-data>` element for `META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE`?

Comment: Yup. Here's the manifest:  `<service
            android:name=".ConnectionQuickSettingsService"
            android:label="@string/quick_setting_tile_connect"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.quicksettings.ACTIVE_TILE"
                       android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>`

Comment: @jcarnide: Then assuming that your `ComponentName` for `requestListeningState()` is pointing to `ConnectionQuickSettingsService`, I would expect this to work. I haven't implemented an active tile, so I don't know if there's stuff the docs are missing. Searching GitHub on `android.service.quicksettings.ACTIVE_TILE` turns up a bunch of hits, so you might poke around those that have it set to `true` and see if there's anything else that they are doing.

Comment: I'm calling the function as follows in `MainActivity`: `ConnectionQuickSettingsService.requestListeningState(getApplicationContext(), getComponentName())`. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @jcarnide: That's the wrong `ComponentName`. If you look inside it, it will identify `MainActivity`. Use the `ComponentName` constructor to create one to identify `ConnectionQuickSettingsService`.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I didn't really understand the purpose of `ComponentName` in that function and there isn't much in the documentation regarding that, which is why I defaulted to `getComponentName()`. Sorry for giving you such a headache.

Comment: but `onStopListening` is being called right away after `onStartListening` and when you toggling some of your feature with activity/widget/custom notification instead of this quick button then state are not sync, it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need all the service connection. I would add the meta data [META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.html#META_DATA_ACTIVE_TILE) to the tile service manifest declaration, and then you can call [TileService.requestListeningState(context, new ComponentName(context, TileService.class));](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.html#requestListeningState(android.content.Context,%20android.content.ComponentName)) which will trigger [onStartListening()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.html#onStartListening()). 
After that onStartListening() could call a method to update the Tile state/label/icon.

Also in your Tile service method to update the tile
I would add a check if (getQsTile !=null)

Comment: where should one call this method?